# Finding an upper bound for a sum over primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Fix $X>\geq 1$ a real number and let $1\leq y<X.$ Is there a positive constant $B$ such that

$$\prod_{y<p\leq X} \left(1+\frac{3}{p}+
\sum_{\nu \geq 2} \frac{(\nu+1)^2}{p^{\nu}}\right)\leq B.$$
Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you want to fix $X$, since for any given $X$ it seems simple to find such a $B$.

Comment: @Slade Could you give me an idea how to find $B$?

Comment: The product is finite.  Just let $B$ be its value when $y=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find a $B$ that works for all $X$ is impossible.

There is a standard result that, if $a_n$ is a sequence with $\sum_n |a_n|^2 < \infty$, then convergence of $\prod_n (1+a_n)$ is equivalent to convergence of $\sum_n a_n$.

Let $a_n = \frac{3}{p_n} + \sum_\nu \frac{(\nu+1)^2}{p_n^\nu} = \frac{3}{p_n} + O(p_n^{-2})$.  Then $\sum_n |a_n|^2$ converges, so we can apply the result.

But the sum of the reciprocals of the primes diverges, so the product diverges as well.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! May I go further in my question? I mean Is there a constant $B=B(X)$ dependng on $X$ which satisfies this inequality?

Comment: @KhadijaMbarki As I said, yes there is: take $y=1$, and let $B(X)$ be the product.

Comment: @KhadijaMbarki Or are you asking for a "nice" _function_ $B(X)$ that bounds the left hand side?  I think the product is approximately $(\ln X)^3$.

Comment: @Slade Are you sure that, as written, your claim is true? Take $a_{n}=-\frac{1}{p_{n}}$. So $\sum\left|a_{n}\right|^{2}$ converges and $\sum a_{n}$ diverges but the product converges to $0$ for the Mertens' theorem. Am I wrong? But it is surely true that the product in the question diverges.

Comment: @MarcoCantarini An infinite product of positive numbers whose limit is zero is usually treated as divergent, because the sum of the logarithms is divergent.  With this caveat, I believe this fact is true for all complex numbers.  But anyway, there are no surprises when $a_n$ is positive.

Comment: @Slade yes and thank you for your proposition of $\log(X)^3$